# iOS - Wrong UIScreen bounds in viewWillTransition for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiscreen, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have to check if my device has changed orientation in iOS 8+.

My approach is:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    let isLand = UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        let isLand2 = UIScreen.main.bounds.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.height


        print("\(isLand) -> \(isLand2)")
    }
}
```

it works fine in iPhone but in iPad `isLand` has already the new value which should be after the orientation completion, so:

Portrait > Landscape: `true -> true`

Landscape > Portrait: `false -> false`

According to the documentation the bounds should change with the orientation so it should have a before/after bounds, shouldn't it?

> **UIScreen main bounds:**
>
> This rectangle is specified in the current coordinate space, which
>   takes into account any interface rotations in effect for the device.
>   Therefore, the value of this property may change when the device
>   rotates between portrait and landscape orientations.

Whereas it works fine both iPhone and iPad if I use the bounds of the current root view controller like this:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    let isLand = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.view.bounds.width > UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.view.bounds.height

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        let isLand2 = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.view.bounds.width > UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!.view.bounds.height


        print("\(isLand) -> \(isLand2)")
    }
}
```

Portrait > Landscape: `false -> true`

Landscape > Portrait: `true -> false`

Comment: Is The viewWillTransition() method called before or after viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try using the containerView of the coordinator context instead.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    let isLand = coordinator.containerView.bounds.width > coordinator.containerView.bounds.height

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        let isLand2 = coordinator.containerView.bounds.width > coordinator.containerView.bounds.height

        print("\(isLand) -> \(isLand2)")
    }

}
```

If you want to get further information regarding the transition you can use the `func view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey)` and `func viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey)` using the `.from` key.